# Why isn't Django displaying my dynamic background images on my template

Tags: django, image, templates, view, model

I am displaying dynamic content from my database on my templates using django. When I check the image url in the google developer console it shows that the url of the image I am trying to display is correct but it still doesn't display the image on the page.

```
template = loader.get_template("selling/shop.html")
    if Product.objects.exists():
        products = Product.objects.all()
        for product in products:
            productimages = product.productimage_set.all()
            for productimage in productimages:
                imageurl = productimage.product_images.url
            context = {
                    "products" : products,
                    "imageurl" : imageurl,
                }



<div class="container" id="storediv" >
   <div  id="noproducts">
     {% if products %}
     {% for product in products %}
     <div class="holla2 col-sm-12 col-lg-3" id="holla" style="background-image: url('{{ product.productimage_set.first.product_images.url }}');">
           <div class="alltext" id="textcontainer">
             <p class="alltext" id="one">{{ product.title}}</p>
             <p id="two">${{ product.price }}</p>
             <!-- <p id="three">{{ product.product_description }}</p> -->
          </div>
    </div>
     {% endfor %}
     {% else %}
     <h2>There don't seem to be any products now. Please check back later!
```

To further clarify, where it says:
 `style="backgroundimage:url('{{product.productimage_set.first.product_images.url }}');"`
is working correctly and displaying the image url but the image isn't showing up on the page.

Comment: Is it the first part of your code your views.py? It's a bit confusing to understand. Can you post your views.py properly and if possible the models.py too so we can see the relationship you have?

Comment: you have mistaken in style. change `backgroundimage` to `background-image`

Answer (score 0):

if your image in your MEDIA_URL you can use below code

```
<header class="masthead" style="background-image:url({{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ object.image.url }});">
```